# How does view merging and predicate evaluation work?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to understand the working of view merging with function calls and how does oracle evaluate the predicate with subquery factoring. Thanks in advance !

Test queries use subquery factoring to specify a single function call per row.
The functions increment the package variable p.call_count that is reset and examined around each test.

Query results are variable on each execution because the function (p.f) is non-deterministic
and will respond 0 or 1 in a random pattern.

**SQL code**

```
create table t as select rownum as i from dual connect by level < 11;

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('test','t');


create or replace package p is
function f return number;
function df return number deterministic;
call_count number:=0;
end p;
/

create or replace package body p is
function f return number is
begin
 call_count:=call_count+1;
 RETURN (mod(ABS(dbms_random.random),2));
end f;
function df return number is
begin
 call_count:=call_count+1;
 RETURN (1);
end df;
end p;
/
set serveroutput on
begin
p.call_count:=0;
end;
/

SELECT *
FROM
(
 WITH x AS (
  SELECT p.f AS n
  FROM t)
 SELECT
  n,
  n AS n2,
  n AS n3
 FROM x
)
WHERE NOT (n = n2 AND n = n3)
/

begin
dbms_output.put_line('Count: '||p.call_count);
end;
/
```

The query either returns zero rows or 10 rows, nothing in between.
There are either:
2x function calls if the result set is empty
32x function calls if the result set is 10-rows

An example result of 10-rows where row 1 contradicts the predicate WHERE NOT (n=n2 AND n=n3)

**Output:**

```
1 1 1
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 1
1 0 1
0 1 1
1 0 1
0 0 1
0 1 1
```

I suspect that the subquery factor and in-line view are being merged by the optimizer.
As the result is either 0 rows or 10 rows, I suspect that the predicate "NOT (n=n2 AND n=n3)"
becomes "NOT (p.f=p.f AND p.f=p.f)".
In other words, the predicate is not applied to the values returned from the subquery and inline view,
but evaluated off completely separate function calls, and the result applied to all rows.

Question:

1. Is this a valid query transformation by the optimizer?
2. For the zero row result, I would have expected a mix of 2 or 3 calls to the function p.f instead of always just 2?
3. For the 10-row result, I would have expected 33 calls to p.f and not 32?
4. Is the optimizer using transitive predicate logic to reduce "NOT (p.f=p.f AND p.f=p.f)" to become "NOT (p.f=p.f)"? This does not seem to be a logically consistent transformation.

Comment: Why do you need to understand this? Are you suggesting that the optimiser is causing the wrong result to be calculated - as this seems to be extremely unlikely?

Comment: Actual predicate can be seen in the execution plan and yes, it is multiple function calls even if you force the optimizer to avoid view merging. And moreover, even when you materialize the first subquery, because the predicate is pushed into it. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=da6bdf8f2e68a91890dbce990d967807).

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit broad because [view merging](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tgsql/query-transformations.html#GUID-38C9EAE6-4E31-4C11-B090-583DD32CE2ED) is a sizeable subject even before you add predicate evaluation, subquery factoring and non-deterministic functions to the mix. I'm not sure non-deterministic functions are ever a good idea in a SQL query.

You can get some insight into internal transformations by using [dbms_utility.expand_sql_text](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/expand-sql-text-12cr1), which (using 21c) gives

```
SELECT "A1"."N" "N","A1"."N2" "N2","A1"."N3" "N3" FROM  (SELECT "A3"."N" "N","A3"."N" "N2","A3"."N" "N3" FROM  (SELECT "WILLIAM"."P"."F"() "N" FROM "WILLIAM"."T" "A2") "A3") "A1" WHERE "A1"."N"<>"A1"."N2" OR "A1"."N"<>"A1"."N3"
```

Formatted and decluttered version:

```
select a1.n, a1.n2, a1.n3
from   ( select a3.n n
              , a3.n n2
              , a3.n n3
         from   (select p.f() n from t a2) a3 ) a1
where  a1.n <> a1.n2
or     a1.n <> a1.n3
```

This isn't the only transformation - you would have to run a 10053 trace to see all the steps the optimiser goes through, and even then I'm not sure it captures the exact final version - but it gives some clue about the kind of transformations that can be applied.